# Where does it store the numbers and how does it know? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

So i found this solution to "Missing Number" problem, i am trying to solve LeetCode problems, but i am very bad!

I added comments to the code below many questions, i did not create this, i found this.

So my main question is: Where does it store the data that it went through numbers 1,2,3,4....

and How does it recognise what is not in the array.... and how does it know what is in the array.

When i look at this code i see it loops through the array, but at what point is the program HOLDUP there something missing here... how does it know ?

i understand whats happening sort of... but then at the same time i understand nothing at all.... please help.

Sorry in advance.

(i am not native english speaker i have watched a few videos on this problem i understand it, but i don't understand how the computer thinks why the computer knows etc)

source of solution below: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-missing-number/

```
void findMissing(int arr[], int N)
{

    int i; // to loop through numbers???
    int temp[N + 1]; // ?? 
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){ // i is beginning of array, and loops through to the end of the array (n)
      temp[i] = 0; // ??
    }
   
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){ //loops through array again
      temp[arr[i] - 1] = 1; // ?? 
    }
 
 
    int ans;
    for (i = 0; i <= N ; i++) { //loops through array again
        if (temp[i] == 0) // Here it find the anwser?
            ans = i  + 1; // the answer?
    }
    std::cout << ans; //printing answer
}
 
/* Driver code */
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 2 }; //array to solve
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); // n is being told what size array is
    findMissing(arr, n); //finding solution.
}
```

`

Comment: This might be worth trying to write out in pencil and paper, watching at each step what happens to the values of `temp`, based on the contents of `arr`. After the second loop, `temp` will have `1` in every position except one. The position which still has a `0` must be the number that was missing from the original array.

Comment: Don't try to learn c++ at places like leetcode. Get a good book. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) for background and ideas where to start.  For instance this: `int temp[N + 1];` is not even legal c++ because N is not a compile time constant.

Comment: You would be *amazed* what you can learn from *working* code by stepping through it in a *debugger* and observing it in action. Debuggers aren't just for finding bugs. They can be incredibly illuminating when used with *working* code.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it on paper maybe its easier there, and im going to check out all the usefull links for c++ thank you!
I have not thought of the debugger techinique yet... i will give it a shot :).

Comment: @ucas Please read a book on C++ for beginners before accessing  LeetCode.

Comment: As an alternative to using pen and paper, you could also add more printout (like std::cout << ans; ) in the loops to make the program print the values of the items you are interested in while it goes through the loops. That way, you will see in the output the change of the values in each step which will help you to understand what is happening.

Comment: This is not the right exercise for your level of knowledge. The exercise is meant for you to figure this algorithm: add all the provided numbers together, subtract from the sum of 1 to n, find your number. This is time O(n), space O(1). the algorithm above is O(n) both for space and time and relies on non-standard VLA. You'd be way better off learning from a real book and when/if you are ready for algorithmic challenges, find a better source

Comment: The indexes in `temp` that are set to `1` are the numbers present in `arr` the one set to `0` is the index of the missing number?

Comment: Im going to be reading c++ primer book now. Any advice on how to practice c++ without leatcode?

Comment: *"`int temp[N + 1]; // ??`"* It is invalid code, as `N` is not a compile time value.

Comment: @lucas Make a pet project. All you need is a text editor, a compiler and a debugger. Gfg is a "coding" website that offers garbage code examples. Avoid it by all means.

Comment: @evg Thank you i will avoid gfg :), thanks everyone for your input i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted above, you should read an intro book to C++ and learn to use a debugger before trying to solve leetcode exercises. This would allow you to use C++ constructs such as std::vector and range loops, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void findMissing(const std::vector<unsigned>& numbers)
{
    std::vector<bool> temp;

    temp.resize(numbers.size()+1); // Solves your holdup, in C you would use memory management functions not appropriate at this point.

    for (auto num : numbers) {
        temp[num-1] = true;
    }

    unsigned ans;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        if (!temp[i]) {
            ans = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << ans; //printing answer
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> numbers{ 1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 2 };
    findMissing(numbers);
}
```

**and** the solution is much simpler. There's a formula for the sum of all the integers from 1 through N - its N*(N+1)/2. The difference between the result of the formula and the sum of numbers in the vector (use std::accumulate) will give you the missing number.